# Worst Performing / Long Running Queries (Teradata)

Tags: query-optimization, teradata, query-performance

First off, let me start by saying that this question has probably been around for long. However, since I am new to Teradata I am requesting some help from you to achieve my goal.

That been said, I am trying to build a query that will show the top 10 worst performing /long-running queries for a given time-frame (usually in the past).
I already did some reading online and came up with few metrics that might help identify such queries :-

```
SELECT    
UserName,
LogDate,
QueryID,
StartTime,
FirstRespTime,
((FirstRespTime - StartTime) HOUR(4) TO SECOND(2)) AS ElapsedTime,
((FirstRespTime - FirstStepTime) HOUR(4) TO SECOND(2)) AS EexecutionTime,
(FirstRespTime - StartTime) HOUR to SECOND(4) AS FirstRespElapsedTime,
ParserCPUTime,
AMPCPUTime,
AMPCPUTime + ParserCPUTime AS TotalCPUTime,
SpoolUsage/(1024*1024*1024) AS Spool_GB,
(MaxAMPCPUTime) * (HASHAMP() + 1) AS ImpactCPU
CAST(100-(nullifzero(AMPCPUTime/HASHAMP() + 1) * 100 /nullifzero(MaxAMPCPUTime)) AS INTEGER ) AS "CPUSkew%",
TotalIOCount,
MaxAMPIO * (HASHAMP() + 1) AS ImpactIO,
CAST(100-((TotalIOCount/HASHAMP() + 1) * 100 /nullifzero(MaxAMPIO)) AS INTEGER ) AS "IOSkew%",
QueryText
FROM pdcrinfo.<tables>
.....
.....
WHERE
logdate BETWEEN <input start-date> AND <input end-date>
AND
AMPCPUTime > 0
```

However, I am still struggling with the following questions -

- Did I get the calculations shown above accurate ?
- Does the above list of metrics suffice ? Or, are there any additional
  metric(s) that need to be included in the above list as well ?
- I am bit confused with the ImpactCPU metric calculation logic. Apart
  from the one mentioned above, I found another logic as
  `ImpactCPU = (max_vproc_CPU * number of vprocs)`. 
  Please indicate the correct one.
- Kindly let me know the history tables to use (in pdcrinfo etc)
- Finally, what logic should I apply to combine all these metrics into one to 
  identify the top 10 ?

We are using Teradata v14.

Any help is highly appreciated. Please let me know if additional information is necessary.

Cheers !

Comment: `max_vproc_CPU` = `MaxAMPCPUTime` and `number of vprocs` = `(HASHAMP() + 1)` . The table is the same as in dbc: `dbqlogtbl_hst`,  but why don't you simply use Viewpoint's **Query Spotlight** which does exactly the same? You can choose the metrics and when you click on the query you get details about resource usage over the runtime...

Comment: @dnoeth thanks for your response. However, I intend to construct a query instead and put it in a Microstrategy report to automate the process so that the management-users can run it by themselves and generate the report and take necessary actions. Also, can I use the following metrics - `PJI = (TotalCPUTime *1000)/TotalIOCount > 6` and `UnnecessaryIO = TotalIOCount/(TotalCPUTime*1000) > 6` ? to determine. Could you please indicate which of the above metrics would suffice.

Comment: The metrics look ok, add whatever you think is neccessary :-) And now you have to decide what are the *top 10*, based on what: runtime, cpu, impactcpu, spool or a combination. You can QUALIFY over ROW_NUMBER(s), but you should reduce the amount of rows by adding more conditions to WHERE like minimum ElapsedTime, Spool, CPU, ect.

Comment: @dnoeth thank you so much for your inputs... i m good from here... i appreciate your help !